# 1.js:23 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I am trying to use drag and drop interface for moving some input within his form and there are the two functions-handlers for that:

```
let drag = (event) => {
    event.dataTransfer.setData("application/x-moz-node", input1);
    event.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = "move";
};

let drop = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    let data = event.dataTransfer.getData("application/x-moz-node");
    event.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
```

and whenever I am trying to drop the input element on it's her position, I get the error. How should I fix it and what is the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getElementById` searches the DOM tree for an element having the id you specified as parameter. In your case it is the value of `input1`.

So, you have to set the `id` of the `div` that you drag to the value of the `input1`.

As I don't think that is what you intended, you should put an id to the draggable element :

```
<div id="draggable-element" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
```

And then :

```
ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById('draggable-element'));
```

Or you can pass it like:

```
event.dataTransfer.setData("application/x-moz-node", input1);
event.dataTransfer.setData("my-draggable-id", ev.target.id);
```

and then :

```
let data = event.dataTransfer.getData("application/x-moz-node");
let draggableId= event.dataTransfer.getData("my-draggable-id");
event.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(draggableId));
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lulylulu/wyk26kL7/)